# Proving that $\frac{1}{1+\text{min}(x,z)}\le\frac{1}{1+\text{min}(x,y)}+\frac{1}{1+\text{min}(y,z)}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $t,p\in \mathbb N$
>
> $$d_4(t,p):=\begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{1+\text{min}(t,p)}\quad \text{ if } t\neq p\\
> 0\quad \quad\quad\quad\text{ if } t= p
> \end{cases}$$

Let $x,y,z\in \mathbb N$
I'm trying to prove:

$$\frac{1}{1+\text{min}(x,z)}\le\frac{1}{1+\text{min}(x,y)}+\frac{1}{1+\text{min}(y,z)}$$

I have idea how to prove it, to split the cases :

$$x>y>z\text{ or } x>y=z\dots$$

but I think that with my idea it will be too long to prove it, is there an easy why ? thanks

Comment: There is something missing before your curly brackets. Moreover, note that
$$ \min(x,z) \geq \min\big(\min(x,y),\min(y,z)\big)$$

Comment: I can add, it is just the name of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x,y,z\in \mathbb N$ we have

$$\min(x,z) \ge \min(\min(x,y), \min(y,z)).$$
Hence, we obtain
$$\frac{1}{1+\min(x,z)} \le \frac1{1+\min(\min(x,y), \min(y,z))} \le \frac1{1+ \min(x,y)} + \frac1{1+\min(y,z)}$$
(as both summands on the right hand side are positive).